# How to resolve an XSS Vulnerability in an href tag?

Tags: security, jsp, xss

I have just started using a web application scanner to see what vulnerabilities my web applications have and am getting results showing xss vulnerabilities in href tags.

For example an alert script can be pushed into the href of the following url:

```
<a href="/contextroot/servlet.do?"><script>alert(81)</script>page=1">2</a>
```

This is just a location where a user can page between a table of different results and is dynamically added to a jsp via a java TagSupport.

I have tried swapping this href location out with a javascript call, but the vulnerability remains. I am starting to suspect there is something fundamental I am missing about xss here. Is there a way to format this tag to make it not vulnerable to xss? Any resources to explain what is going on? I have tried researching without a ton of luck...

Comment: I'd imagine (I can't be definate as you haven't shown the code) that where the script tag is inserted your reading some other value (from somewhere) and appending it into the HTML. That's what you need to be looking for. What code produces this `<a>` tag?

Comment: It's an anchor tag, with a `href` attribute.  You don't format the tag to prevent XSS, you format the suspicious value inserted by your Java TagSupport so it can't harbor an XSS attack.

Comment: _“For example an alert script can be pushed into the href of the following url”_ - how? Which part of that is your system generating dynamically, and where does it take the values from?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a typical case of [Reflected XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Reflected_Cross_site_scripting_(OTG-INPVAL-001)).

---

Most likely, the server reads url parameters, without escaping them, and injects 
directly into the DOM. Then it servers the DOM to the user, leading to a behaviour where arbitrary script can be injected into the DOM.

Solution: Server should escape / sanitize query parameters before injecting them into DOM.

PS. Very unlikely, but it could also be the client (meaning JavaScript) that extracts the query parameters and injects them into the DOM.